# How to get the textview values from recyclerview for each item row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview where I am displaying the items with Itemname, Itemrate and quantity of the items which is increased and decreased by +/- buttons respectively. now, i want to get all the values from each item of the recyclerview and send it over the server or save it to local database so how to achieve this.?

//This is My Adapter Class

public class TeaListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    //private int num=0;
    private List<TeaListPOJO> teaItemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor cursor;
    int comboCount;

    HashMap<Object,Integer> selectedMap = new HashMap ();

    private String ItemName;
    private String itemrate;
    private String qty;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvitemName, tvitemRate,tvcount; //number
        public ImageView ivItemImg,ivPlus,ivMinus;
        public Button btnIncrease,btnDecrease;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvitemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_name);
            tvitemRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_price);
            ivItemImg= (ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.iv_item);
            ivPlus=(ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.row_view_final_order_iv_plus);
            ivMinus=(ImageView) view.findViewById (R.id.row_view_final_order_iv_minus);
            tvcount=(TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.row_view_final_order_tv_count);
        }
    }


    public TeaListAdapter(List<TeaListPOJO> teaItemList) {
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.cursor=cursor;
        this.teaItemList = teaItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rv_placeorder_items, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder (itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        TeaListPOJO tealist = teaItemList.get(position);
        holder.tvitemName.setText(tealist.getItemName ());
        holder.tvitemRate.setText(AppConstants.INDIAN_RUPEE_SIGN.concat (tealist.getItemRate ()));

        holder.ivPlus.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int count=0;
                try{
                    count = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvcount.getText().toString());
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                //count++;
                count = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvcount.getText().toString());
                holder.tvcount.setText(String.valueOf(count+ 1));
            }

        });

        holder.ivMinus.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int count=0;
                try{

                    count = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvcount.getText().toString());
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                if(count>0) {
                    //count--;
                    count = Integer.parseInt (holder.tvcount.getText ().toString ());
                    holder.tvcount.setText (String.valueOf (count - 1));
                }
            }

        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

       /* Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PlaceOrderActivity.class);
        //            intent.putExtra("quantity",Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
        intent.putExtra ("quantity", qty);
        intent.putExtra ("item", ItemName);
        intent.putExtra ("itemrate", itemrate);

         ItemName = holder.tvitemName.getText().toString();
         qty = holder.tvcount.getText().toString();
         itemrate=holder.tvitemRate.getText ().toString ();

        Log.e("rate",itemrate);
        Log.e("qty",qty);*/


        byte[] decodedString = new byte[0];
        try {

            decodedString = Base64.decode(tealist.getImageStr(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            // tenantModelPOJO.setLogo(decodedString);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            holder.ivItemImg.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 50, 50,false));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return teaItemList.size();
    }
```

}

//This is My Activity Class

public class PlaceOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppConstants, View.OnClickListener, WLAPIcalls.OnAPICallCompleteListener {

```
private List<TeaListPOJO> teaList = new ArrayList<> ();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TeaListAdapter mAdapter;
private View view;
private Button btnPlaceorder;
EditText edtmsg;

public String str;

private Context mContext = PlaceOrderActivity.this;
private int itemCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_place_order);
    str=getIntent ().getStringExtra ("quantity");
    edtmsg= (EditText) view.findViewById (R.id.et_message);
    edtmsg.setText (str);

    setRecyclerView (view);
    getallTeaItems ();
}

List<TeaListPOJO> getTeaItemList(String str) {
    Gson gson = new Gson ();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TeaListPOJO>> () {
    }.getType ();
    List<TeaListPOJO> myModelList = gson.fromJson (str, listType);
    return myModelList;
}

private List<TeaListPOJO> getallTeaItems() {
    if (new AppCommonMethods (mContext).isNetworkAvailable ()) {
        WLAPIcalls mAPIcall = new WLAPIcalls (mContext, getString (R.string.getTeaItem), this);
        mAPIcall.GetTeaItemList ();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText (mContext, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    }
    return null;
}


void setRecyclerView(View view) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new TeaListAdapter (teaList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getApplicationContext ());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator ());
    recyclerView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onAPICallCompleteListner(Object item, String flag, String result) throws JSONException {
    if (getString (R.string.getTeaItem).equals (flag)) {
        Log.e ("Result", result);
        teaList = getTeaItemList (result);
        setRecyclerView (view);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the `TeaListPOJO` should also need a field for storing the `count`. Increment or decrement the `count` value when user's clicks on the + or - button and display the `count` value to the textview, instead of directly diplaying.

```
class TeaListPojo{
    private int count;
    .....

    public int getCount()
        return this.count
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for updating the count textview

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    TeaListPOJO tealist = teaItemList.get(position);

    .....
    .....

    holder.ivPlus.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tealist.setCount( tealist.getCount() + 1);
            holder.tvcount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }

    });

    holder.ivMinus.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                tealist.setCount(tealist.getCount() - 1)
                holder.tvcount.setText (String.valueOf (count));
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: How can i set the count and pass it to the textview

Comment: you should increment or decrement the value of `count`, i will add a pseduo code

Comment: i have added the code, a condition can also given to prevent the count from going negative

Comment: its a psedo code, don't use the exact code in your project, just see what i have done inside the OnClickListerner

Comment: I didn't used the code exactly, i just tried to set the value of count to the textview but while clicking on button its not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra property in your `TeaListPOJO` model say `count` when you press +/- button you have to set count in your model like you set the count in your text view. So in your adapter you have `TeaListPOJO` list. Show when you want to send data to server get list of `TeaListPOJO` and also you have list of count.

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter set a call to the API to change the value in the DB.
You shouldn't need to pass the entire data, usually you'll be able to just update that one object you're looking at by passing the id in the URL.
e.g.
https://hostname.domain/api/object/ID
Use a PUT request and pass the info from the object in that row.

If you're creating the back-end of this too then I'd highly suggest you set this up as passing the entire dataset for all rows is not exactly an ideal solution.

If these didn't exist in the first place and they are all created from being in the app then have a button on your main activity that saves the list, then pass the entire list to an API call, most likely will need to parse the data into JSON.
I assume here that if the latter is the case that you have created these objects in a class.